# Using sqlite3 database in Android Application

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, google-maps

Hey guys I am trying to use sqlite3 database to use in this android application I am making.
We have a database we made that has the bus schedule and the bus stops 
So the queries like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.departure_time, N.trip_headsign
FROM mt_stop_time M, mt_trip N
WHERE (M.stop_id=8338) AND (M.trip_id = N.trip_id) AND (M.day = 'su') 
AND (M.departure_time < 18) AND (M.departure_time >= 15) AND M.trip_id LIKE '%2010_11%' ORDER BY trip_headsign ASC;
```

will return something like

```
17:26:00 1 SPRING GARDEN TO DARTMOUTH
17:41:00 1 SPRING GARDEN TO DARTMOUTH
17:56:00 1 SPRING GARDEN TO DARTMOUTH
15:26:00 10 WESTPHAL
16:26:00 10 WESTPHAL
17:26:00 10 WESTPHAL
15:13:00 14 DOWNTOWN
16:13:00 14 DOWNTOWN
17:17:00 80 HALIFAX
17:47:00 80 HALIFAX
```

It shows the Time, bus #, destination
So my question is how can I call sqlite3 through Java so I can use these informations for my application to show up the bus schedule time once the user clicks the bus stops?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ["using the database"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) documentation in the android docs.

Comment: we have looked at the documentations in the android docs but our problem is converting the database we have in sqlite3 so we can call it in Java for us to use it in our application. Any additional help would be great

Comment: WHat do you mean with "convert existing database"? Is this mysql or oracle?